# how to search an array list for matching elements then create a list with those elements

Tags: java, arrays, list

My program for university allows me to search for parts in an arraylist i created. My goal now is to apply a filter to search for specific types of parts such as 'cpu'.

This is what i'm trying to do, i input a word, the word is sent to a loop which checks if any element in the list has that word; if it does, then it will add it to a new list and print it. However this is just printing an empty loop. I'm trying to get it working for just the type of item, then i'll do the price.

```
private void filter(){
    System.out.print("Enter type of part to view ('all' for no filtering): ");
    String filterPart = In.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter minimum price ('-1' for no filtering): ");
    double minPrice  = In.nextDouble();
    catalogue.LoopSearch(filterPart);
}
```

And here is the LoopSearch Method

```
public Part LoopSearch(String filterPart){
    List<Part> list2 = new ArrayList<Part>();
    for (Part part : parts) {
    if (part.hasName(filterPart)) {
        list2.add(part);
    }

    System.out.print(list2);
}
return null;



}
```

lastly, this is the hasName method

```
public boolean hasName(String filterPart) {
       return filterPart.equals(this.name);
}
```

Comment: Your logic seems fine to me. Your code `System.out.print(list2);` is not in correct place and also is not the correct way to print item in list. You should put the print logic before `return null;`. Use `list2.forEach(part -> System.out.println(part.getName))`. If it is still not working, then check if casing of `filterPart` and `name` of `Part` is same.

Answer (score 1):

The following code can be used to filter the elements:

```
List<Part> newParts = parts.stream()
 .filter(p -> p.hasName(filterPart))
 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but maybe provide a little more context for the answer you gave